# Convert incoming email from plain text to HTML

Tags: 2010, development, multiline-text-field

I have a list that accepts emails and creates list items out of them.

The issue I'm facing is that if someone emails the list using plain text, the formatting showing up in a list item's multi-line text column is barely readable (no newlines or anything).

I want to be able to translate plain text into HTML so that the multi-line rich text field reflects its formatting, in C#.

I've tried the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` but the formatting is still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string parseText(string text, bool allow)
{
    //Create a StringBuilder object from the string input parameter            
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    //Replace all double white spaces with a single white space and &nbsp;
    sb.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

    //Check if HTML tags are not allowed
    if (!allow)
    {
        //Convert the brackets into HTML equivalents
        sb.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        sb.Replace(">", "&gt;");
        //Convert the double quote
        sb.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
    }
    //Create a StringReader from the processed string of the StringBuilder
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    //Loop while next character exists
    while (sr.Peek() > -1)
    {
        //Read a line from the string and store it to a temp variable
        string temp = sr.ReadLine();
        //write the string with the HTML break tag
        //Note here write method writes to a Internal StringBuilder
        //object created automatically
        sw.Write(temp + "<br>");
    }
    //Return the final processed text
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/saurabhnandu/TexttoHTMLParser12032005072354AM/TexttoHTMLParser.aspx